How can I "tell" Drizzle if a migration is considered "done" when migrating from Prisma?
I'm migrating my project from Prisma to Drizzle following the migration guide and I've bumped into a problem. Drizzle correctly generates a migration file that says:
-- Current sql file was generated after introspecting the database
-- If you want to run this migration please uncomment this code before executing migrations

my problem is that this will fail when I start my application:
await client.connect();
// This command run all migrations from the migrations folder and apply changes to the database
await migrate(db, {
    migrationsFolder: resolve(__dirname, "../src/drizzle"),
});

with:
error: unterminated /* comment at or near "/*
DO $$ BEGIN
 CREATE TYPE "public"."AccountProvider" AS ENUM('LOCAL', 'DISCORD');
EXCEPTION
 WHEN duplicate_object THEN null;
END $$;
"

so right after the unterminated /* that comes with the script. If I uncomment this script then it fails with some other error.
It is clear that this migration shouldn't run at all, since it was generated from my existing schema (so no migration is necessary). Is there a way to mark a migration as "done"? I checked and Drizzle created a drizzle schema in my database with an empty __drizzle_migrations table.
